# Retrieve attributes from object

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

I'm pretty much brand new to Xcode. I'm trying to retrieve information on an artist from a sqlite3 database. The following is where I insert the artist:

```
- (IBAction)addArtistButton:(id)sender 
{
    NSString *artist_Name = artistFirstNameField.text;
    NSString *artist_LastName = artistLastNameField.text;
    NSString *artist_Phone = artistPhone.text;
    NSString *artist_Address = artistAddress.text;
    NSString *artist_Email = artistEmail.text;
    NSString *artist_Bio = artistBio.text;
    NSString *artist_SundayHours = artistSundayHours.text;
    NSString *artist_MondayHours = artistMondayHours.text;
    NSString *artist_TuesdayHours = artistTuesdayHours.text;
    NSString *artist_WednesdayHours = artistWednesdayHours.text;
    NSString *artist_ThursdayHours = artistThursdayHours.text;
    NSString *artist_FridayHours = artistFridayHours.text;
    NSString *artist_SaturdayHours = artistSaturdayHours.text;

    int SunOn = artistSundayOn.on;
    int MonOn = artistMondayOn.on;
    int TueOn = artistTuesdayOn.on;
    int WedOn = artistWednesdayOn.on;
    int ThurOn = artistThursdayOn.on;
    int FriOn = artistFridayOn.on;
    int SatOn = artistSaturdayOn.on;

    if (sqlite3_open([dbPathString UTF8String], &artistDB)==SQLITE_OK) {


        NSString *insertStmt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO ARTISTS(NAME, LASTNAME, PHONE, ADDRESS, EMAIL, BIO, SUNDAY_HOURS, MONDAY_HOURS, TUESDAY_HOURS, WEDNESDAY_HOURS, THURSDAY_HOURS, FRIDAY_HOURS, SATURDAY_HOURS, SUNDAY_ON, MONDAY_ON, TUESDAY_ON, WEDNESDAY_ON, THURSDAY_ON, FRIDAY_ON, SATURDAY_ON) values ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%d', '%d', '%d', '%d', '%d', '%d', '%d')",[artist_Name UTF8String], [artist_LastName UTF8String], [artist_Phone UTF8String], [artist_Address UTF8String], [artist_Email UTF8String], [artist_Bio UTF8String], [artist_SundayHours UTF8String], [artist_MondayHours UTF8String], [artist_TuesdayHours UTF8String], [artist_WednesdayHours UTF8String], [artist_ThursdayHours UTF8String], [artist_FridayHours UTF8String], [artist_SaturdayHours UTF8String], SunOn, MonOn, TueOn, WedOn, ThurOn, FriOn, SatOn];
        const char *insert_stmt = [insertStmt UTF8String];
        char *error;

        if (sqlite3_exec(artistDB, insert_stmt, NULL, NULL, &error)==SQLITE_OK) {

            // NSLog(@"Insert: %s", insert_stmt);

            Artists *Artist = [[Artists alloc]init];
            [Artist setNAME:artist_Name];
            [Artist setLASTNAME:artist_LastName];

            [arrayOfArtist addObject:Artist];
            NSLog(@"Added artist");

        }else{ NSLog(@"Uh Oh: %s", error); 
        }
        sqlite3_close(artistDB);
    }else{ NSLog(@"Unable to open artistDB"); 
    }
}
```

And here is what I have for now to get information out.

```
 -(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    //UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    UILabel *last  = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:200];

    NSLog(@"arrayOfArtist: %@", arrayOfArtist);

    last.text   = [arrayOfArtist objectAtIndex:2];

    [cell.layer setBorderWidth:2.0f];
    [cell.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
    [cell.layer setCornerRadius:20.0f];

    return cell;
}

Right now those NSLog entries result in the following:

    2013-12-09 21:26:22.855 InkStudiosNav[24585:70b] arrayOfArtist: (
    "<Artists: 0x8ab96a0>",
    "<Artists: 0x8abede0>",
    "<Artists: 0x8abf010>")
    2013-12-09 21:26:22.856 InkStudiosNav[24585:70b] -[Artists length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8abf010
    2013-12-09 21:26:23.106 InkStudiosNav[24585:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Artists length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8abf010'
    *** First throw call stack:
    (
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x0182b5e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x015ae8b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
        2   CoreFoundation                      0x018c8903 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
        3   CoreFoundation                      0x0181b90b ___forwarding___ + 1019
        4   CoreFoundation                      0x0181b4ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
        5   Foundation                          0x011f38ed -[NSConcreteMutableAttributedString replaceCharactersInRange:withString:] + 39
        6   Foundation                          0x011f455a -[NSConcreteMutableAttributedString initWithString:attributes:] + 293
        7   UIKit                               0x004c9bc6 -[UILabel _setText:] + 97
        8   UIKit                               0x004c9d84 -[UILabel setText:] + 40
        9   InkStudiosNav                       0x000048ce -[SecondViewController collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:] + 318
        10  UIKit                               0x0092ebc8 -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:] + 257
        11  UIKit                               0x00930217 -[UICollectionView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 3677
        12  UIKit                               0x0093357f -[UICollectionView layoutSubviews] + 267
        13  UIKit                               0x00387267 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 355
        14  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x015c081f -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
        15  QuartzCore                          0x03c392ea -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
        16  QuartzCore                          0x03c2d0d4 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
        17  QuartzCore                          0x03c2cf40 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 26
        18  QuartzCore                          0x03b94ae6 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 294
        19  QuartzCore                          0x03b95e71 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 393
        20  QuartzCore                          0x03b96544 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 92
        21  CoreFoundation                      0x017f34ce __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
        22  CoreFoundation                      0x017f341f __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 399
        23  CoreFoundation                      0x017d1344 __CFRunLoopRun + 1076
        24  CoreFoundation                      0x017d0ac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
        25  CoreFoundation                      0x017d08db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
        26  GraphicsServices                    0x037d09e2 GSEventRunModal + 192
        27  GraphicsServices                    0x037d0809 GSEventRun + 104
        28  UIKit                               0x0031cd3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
        29  InkStudiosNav                       0x000054dd main + 141
        30  libdyld.dylib                       0x01d6c70d start + 1
    )
    libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
    (lldb)
```

I'm trying to retrieve "NAME" and "LASTNAME" from the table/db.  Can anyone help me? I've been googling for several hours but apparently I'm not googling the correct terminology or something.

The code to insert the artist is working fine and I've viewed the database entries using `SQLite3 Database` browser.

Comment: I don't think the code you posted is causing this error. You should try putting a breakpoint on exceptions and seeing what code is calling `objectForKey:` on an Artist object by accident, which is what your error says.

Comment: Sorry, that was from another NSLog. I removed the NSLog statement but forgot to remove the output. I've removed it now.

Comment: Your log still says "-[Artists objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8a5db00" meaning that your program is crashing because you're sending `objectForKey:` to an Artists object.

Comment: I'll rerun with updated code and update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your backtrace, it appears this line is the problem:

```
last.text   = [arrayOfArtist objectAtIndex:2];
```

You're assigning an `Artists` instead of an `NSString` to last.text here. Did you mean:

```
last.text   = [[arrayOfArtist objectAtIndex:2] NAME];
```

Or something similar?

Comment: That gave me the hint I needed, thanks! I used the following to give the correct name on each row:

last.text   = [[arrayOfArtist objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] LASTNAME];